# Superimposed JPanels not lining up

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying to make a paintable JPanel, with optional gridline display. To do this, I have a custom JPanel, which makes another JPanel that holds just the gridlines. That way, I can show / hide the grid lines without ever removing what is on the canvas.

All seems to be working, except for some weird alignment issues I can seem to pin down. When I start drawing some squares, they are only a few pixels above the gridlines. How can I fix this so that both panels are displaying EXACTLY on top of one another?

Here is an example of the issue:
[image: An Example of the grid]

```
package com.carvethsolutions.guilib.customcomp;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

/**
 * A custom component for displaying a grid
 */
public class GridCanvas extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

/**
 * Width and height of the canvas, in pixels
 */
private int width, height;

/**
 * How many pixels represent one square on the grid
 */
private int gridScale;

/**
 * The separate panel that holds the grid lines
 */
private JPanel gridPanel;

private boolean gridLinesVisible = true;

/**
 * Holds color selections
 */
private Paintbrush paintbrush;

public GridCanvas() {
    super();
    width = 500;
    height = 500;

    setupComponent();
}

public GridCanvas(int width, int height) {
    super();
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    setupComponent();
}

/**
 * Private function to prepare the component.
 */
private void setupComponent() {
    gridScale = 50;
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    this.addMouseListener(this);

    gridPanel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            // Vertical Lines
            for (int x = gridScale; x <= width; x += gridScale) {
                g.drawLine(x, 0, x, height);
            }

            for (int y = gridScale; y <= height; y += gridScale) {
                g.drawLine(0, y, width, y);
            }
        }
    };

    gridPanel.setVisible(gridLinesVisible);
    gridPanel.setPreferredSize(this.getPreferredSize());
    this.add(gridPanel);

    this.setSize(gridPanel.getSize());
    paintbrush = new Paintbrush(Color.black);
}

/**
 * Enable or disable grid lines from appearing on the Canvas
 */
public void toggleGridlines() {
    gridLinesVisible = !gridLinesVisible;
    gridPanel.setVisible(gridLinesVisible);
}


/**
 * Invoked when the mouse button has been clicked (pressed
 * and released) on a component.
 *
 * @param e
 */
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX() / gridScale;
    int y = e.getY() / gridScale;

    System.out.println("mouseClicked Event : (" + x + ", " + y + ")");

    this.getGraphics().setColor(paintbrush.getColor());
    this.getGraphics().fillRect(x * gridScale, y * gridScale, gridScale, gridScale);
}

/**
 * Invoked when a mouse button has been pressed on a component.
 *
 * @param e
 */
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

/**
 * Invoked when a mouse button has been released on a component.
 *
 * @param e
 */
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

/**
 * Invoked when the mouse enters a component.
 *
 * @param e
 */
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

/**
 * Invoked when the mouse exits a component.
 *
 * @param e
 */
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: Myself, I wouldn't use overlying JPanels. Instead I'd try to keep things simpler, such as a single drawing JPanel or a grid of components.

Comment: The whole point is to have the gridlines toggleable, which Camickr and you both seem to ignore

Comment: You can't unpaint something (like the gridlines) without unpainting everything else as well

Comment: So? The super.paintComponent takes care of that for you. You are not painting correctly at all as per @camickr's answer. If you do it all within a single paintComponent method, you can easily turn on and off grid lines using a simple boolean field while leaving the squares in place.

Comment: Clearly I'm painting correctly since I see the squares being painted. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: minimize your GUI and then re-show it to see how "correctly" you're painting. Are your images durable when you do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169995/discussion-between-dtroll-mc-and-dontknowmuchbut-getting-better).

Comment: (1-) `The whole point is to have the gridlines toggleable` - which is addressed in my answer. `Clearly I'm painting correctly since I see the squares being painted.` - clearly you are not for the reasons I gave you.

Answer (score 2):

> To do this, I have a custom JPanel, which makes another JPanel that holds just the gridlines. That way, I can show / hide the grid lines without ever removing what is on the canvas.

Well, that is the wrong approach. Your panel should have properties:

1. paint the gridlines or not
2. a 2D array to control which squares should be filled.

Your paint logic is wrong:

```
this.getGraphics().setColor(paintbrush.getColor());
this.getGraphics().fillRect(x * gridScale, y * gridScale, gridScale, gridScale);
```

You should never use getGraphics(...) on a component to do custom painting. The first time Swing determines the components needs to be repainted you will lose all the painting. For example if you resize the frame.

Instead. custom painting must be done in the `paintComponent()` of the component. Then you:

1. first paint the gridlines if required
2. iterate through the 2D array and paint any squares as required.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Or instead of the 2D Array, use an ArrayList to contain objects to be painted. This object could simply be a `Point` object to control the x/y location of a square to be painted, or is could be an object that contains complete information about the object to be painted such as location/color/shape. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example of this approach.